# Pushing mark down file

Tags: markdown, github-for-windows

I am having an issue editing a mark down file and pushing it to the repo which I have created in Github. I have created a text file `HelloWorld.md` and created a repo in Github. How do I edit the md file and push it to the repo in Github.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can edit the file with notepad or any text editor.
2. `add` the file to the staging area with `git add HelloWorld.md`
3. `commit` the file to your local repository with `git commit -m "edit md"`
4. `push` the file to Github with `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily with download this application
**https://desktop.github.com/**
first clone your remote repo
after add to changing markdown file in local repo
after press "commit to master" button in app